# Laptop monitor running on Microsoft Basic Display Adapter

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I bought a new Laptop and ran into quite some issues ever since.
The biggest one I currently have is, that my laptop monitor is running on Microsoft "Basic Display Adapter", which appears to completely disable my GPU which is constantly running on 0% usage.

However, when I connect a second screen, set it as my main monitor, and have my programs displayed on that one, my GPU is being engaged and everything is working as I expect it.

I've been googling this issue for hours now and just can't find a solution. Help would be appreciated!

(I'm running Windows 10 and my GPU is a NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic display adapter is actually a driver that is built into Windows that provides display and graphics capabilities when software from your hardware manufacturer isn't installed.

It's most commonly there after a fresh reinstall of the OS and there is no GPU driver, whether integrated or dedicated, detected. If you go into device manager and you have the driver for the GTX 1060 installed, you can go ahead and uninstall the Microsoft Basic Display adapter. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Only problem is that  Microsoft "Basic Display Adapter" keeps reinstalling itself when the  computer is being rebooted

Comment: Hmmmm that's a new one for me. Instead of uninstalling it, you could try right clicking on it and select disable. The fact that it keeps reinstalling makes it seem like the OS is not seeing your GTX 1060 when you first boot it. Does the GTX 1060 have the most recent drivers installed from the [Nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)?

Comment: yes I installed the newest drivers today, disabling just causes to completely mess up the graphics and when I check what the monitor is running on it still says Basic Display Adapter

Comment: Does your laptop by chance have the hybrid feature where it switches between integrated and dedicated graphics?

Comment: I think it does. Maybe worth mentioning might be that i can't access the nvidia control panel after uninstalling the basic display adapter

Comment: If you have the hybrid feature and it's trying to switch between dedicated/integrated it could be that you also do not have the integrated graphics installed. So when the PC boots and is looking to use the integrated, there are none present and it installs the basic driver. So I would also get the drivers for the integrated graphics, install them, verify they are present in device manager, and then remove the Microsoft basic driver. That *should* resolve the issue.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems like I don't have the integrated intel graphics installed, and the manual for installing them even states that windows falls back on Microsoft Basic Diaplay Adapter because of that. I will attempt that and will let you know of the result! :)

Comment: it worked like a charm! thank you so much! :)